# Trying to get a Pine Script delete.label to work

Tags: pine-script

Can anyone help me with deleting this label and line when the opposite 'if' statement happens, so when 'os == 0 ? na : vashort' fires, i was wanting label_long and line_long to delete  . thanks in advance

```
if os == 0 ? na : valong
var label label_long=na
var line line_long=na
label.delete(label_long[1])
line.delete(line_long[1])

label_long:=label.new(x=time + 22 * dt, y=fixnan(valong), text= " Long Entry: " + 
tostring(valong,"#") , xloc=xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.price, style= label.style_none, 
textcolor=color.white, size=size.normal,textalign=text.align_right)
line_current:=line.new(x1=time, y1=fixnan(valong),x2=time + round(change(time)*2), 
y2=fixnan(valong), xloc=xloc.bar_time, style=line.style_solid,color=color.yellow,width = 1, 
extend = extend.right)
```

Answer (score 0):

The label.delete seems to be buggy. You should **update** the same label, this way, it will 'delete' the old position of your label and 'create' the new one.
See the example below with your label_long :

```
var label label_long = na

label.set_xy(label_long, time + 22 * dt, fixnan(valong) )
label.set_text(label_long, " Long Entry: " + tostring(valong,"#") )
label.set_yloc(label_long, yloc.pricer)
label.set_style(label_long, label.style_none)
label.set_size(label_long, size.normal)
label.set_color(label_long, color.white)
```