# Pinescript `label.delete` does not seem to be working

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

### Details

I am creating a log system in Pinescript to allow merging together logs that are written to the same index. The code seems to work perfectly fine as can be seen in the figure:

before new candle

[image: 1]

but when a new candle is drawn, the previous label is not deleted despite the command `label.delete(aNewLabel[1])`.

after new candle

[image: 2]

Is there any reason why `label.delete` would not be working as expected?

### Full code:

```
var print_stack_absciss = array.new_int()
var print_stack_string = array.new_string()
var print_stack_color = array.new_color()
var print_stack_range = array.new_int(2, 0)

secondsToTime(seconds) =>
    int res = 1000 * seconds
    res

getDt() =>
    int dt = secondsToTime(timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period))
    dt

getBarIndexAtTime(int _time_point) =>
    int m_bar_ind = na
    int i = 0
    for count = 0 to 5000
        if time[count] >= _time_point and time[count + 1] < _time_point
            m_bar_ind := count
            break
    // @returns
    m_bar_ind

timeToIndex(theTime) =>
    int index = getBarIndexAtTime(theTime)
    index

daysToTime(days)=>
    int theTimeDiff = math.round(days*86400000)

indexToTime(index) =>
    int theTime = na
    if index >= 0
        theTime := time[index]
    else
        theTime := time - index * getDt()
        // theTime := time + daysToTime(2)
    theTime

getAbsciss(absciss, cfg="index") =>
    int indexToUse = na
    int timeToUse = na
    switch cfg
        "index" =>
            indexToUse := absciss
            timeToUse := indexToTime(absciss)
        "time" =>
            indexToUse := timeToIndex(absciss)
            timeToUse := absciss
    [indexToUse, timeToUse]

print(txt = "", color=color.gray, absciss=0, ordinate=0, where=low, size=1, cfg="index") =>
    if barstate.islast
        [indexToUse, timeToUse] = getAbsciss(absciss, cfg)
        int lowRange = array.get(print_stack_range, 0)
        int highRange = array.get(print_stack_range, 1)
        if indexToUse > highRange
            array.set(print_stack_range, 1, indexToUse)
        if indexToUse < lowRange
            array.set(print_stack_range, 0, indexToUse)            
        print_stack_absciss.push(timeToUse)
        print_stack_color.push(color)
        print_stack_string.push(txt)

GetLabels() =>
    int size = array.size(print_stack_absciss)
    // print(str.format("size is {0}", size))
    if size > 0
        for j = array.get(print_stack_range, 0) to array.get(print_stack_range, 1)
            int time_j = indexToTime(j)
            // print(str.format("j is {0}", j))
            strings = array.new_string(0, "")
            color color_i = na
            for i = 0 to size - 1
                // print(str.format("i is {0}", i))
                int absciss_i = array.get(print_stack_absciss, i)
                // print(str.format("absciss_i is {0}", absciss_i))
                if absciss_i == time_j
                    string string_i = array.get(print_stack_string, i)
                    strings.push(string_i)
                    color_i := array.get(print_stack_color, i)
            if array.size(strings)
                // printB(str.format("{0}", indexToTime(j)))
                aNewLabel = label.new(time_j, high[(j<0)?0:j], array.join(strings, "\n"), style = label.style_label_down, color = color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor = color_i, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
                label.delete(aNewLabel[1])

//@version=5
indicator("Label Test")
print(str.format("Number is: {0}", 2), absciss = -20)
print(str.format("Test is: {0}", 3), absciss = -20)
print(str.format("Number is: {0}", 4), absciss = -10)
print(str.format("Test is: {0}", 5), absciss = -10)

GetLabels()
```

I was expecting that whenever a new candle is drawn, the old label would be deleted. I tried to use the strategy present in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72378506/20200618) but I did not have success in doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the best way to avoid repeated label printing (which looks almost like a shadow) is to first define a var label and then immediately delete the label. Then use label.new to make your new label.  What remains is the last label.  Note:  Use Var to define the variable.  Here's an example:

```
var label myLabel = na
label.delete(myLabel) 

myLabel := label.new(x = bar_index, y = high, color=blue, size=size.auto, textcolor = color.white, text = "This is label text", style=label.style_label_left)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `var label` and pass it to your function. In there, you should call `label.set*()` functions to modify the existing label.

```
GetLabels(lbl) =>
    int size = array.size(print_stack_absciss)
    // print(str.format("size is {0}", size))
    if size > 0
        for j = array.get(print_stack_range, 0) to array.get(print_stack_range, 1)
            int time_j = indexToTime(j)
            // print(str.format("j is {0}", j))
            strings = array.new_string(0, "")
            color color_i = na
            for i = 0 to size - 1
                // print(str.format("i is {0}", i))
                int absciss_i = array.get(print_stack_absciss, i)
                // print(str.format("absciss_i is {0}", absciss_i))
                if absciss_i == time_j
                    string string_i = array.get(print_stack_string, i)
                    strings.push(string_i)
                    color_i := array.get(print_stack_color, i)
            if array.size(strings)
                // printB(str.format("{0}", indexToTime(j)))
                label.set_xy(lbl, time_j, high[(j<0)?0:j])
                label.set_text(lbl, array.join(strings, "\n"))
                label.set_textcolor(lbl, color_i)

var label lbl = label.new(na, na, na, style = label.style_label_down, color = color.new(color.white, 100), xloc=xloc.bar_time)

GetLabels(lbl)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution solves the blurred labels being print on top of each other, but it does not print all the labels that were supposed to be print as can be seen in https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoZrE.png.

Comment: Then you need a `var label[]`. My example only shows it for one label only.

Comment: I prepared this: https://pastebin.com/FDG28tFp but it is still getting blurred. When declared labels as var, TV complained about memory limits exceeded.